# too many arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to learn c++ to do some random projects with arduino, recently I wrote this tiny bit of code but i can't manage to make it work. It keeps on telling me that there are "too many arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'".
Any suggestions?

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(1 , INPUT);
 pinMode(2 , INPUT);
 pinMode(3 , INPUT);
 pinMode(13 , OUTPUT);
 pinMode(12 , OUTPUT);
 pinMode(11 , OUTPUT);
 pinMode(14 , OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  int sensorVal = digitalRead(1);
  int sensorVal = digitalRead(2);
  int sensorVal = digitalRead(3);

  Serial.println(sensorVal);

  if (sensorVal == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(11, LOW && 14, LOW);
  }else {
      digitalWrite(11, HIGH && 14, HIGH)
  }

  if (sensorVal == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(12, LOW && 14, LOW);
  }else {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH && 14, HIGH)
  }

    if (sensorVal == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW && 14, LOW);
 } else {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH && 14, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"too many arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'".* -- What exactly in that error message is not understood?

Comment: How many arguments does the *manual* say you need to provide and how many arguments do you actually provide?

Comment: That's not the only problem. Why are you reading from 3 pins into the same variable, which is declared 3 times? Why are you reading from the TX pin? And what makes you think `11, LOW && 14, LOW` should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
digitalWrite(11, LOW && 14, LOW);
```

I'm *guessing* that you think that will drive both pin 11 and 14 low, as in "digital write 11 low and 14 low".

But that's not really how it works, the function expects *one* pin and *one* level. Hence you need to do them sequentially with something like:

```
digitalWrite(11, LOW);
digitalWrite(14, LOW);
```

Comment: Well done for reverse engineering the OP's thought processes!

Comment: The OP might want to add `void DigitalWrite2( uint8_t pin1, uint8_t pin2, uint8_t level) { DigitalWrite(pin1, level); DigitalWrite(pin2, level); }` and call that in all the appropriate places.